# write linq query results to file and attach to smtp email mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, email, smtp

i am trying to attach a file i have written to the email im sending, but for some reason its just downloading and not attaching the right file. This is what i have so far.What am i ding wrong?

```
 public void ConnectToDatabase(UCountRewards uc)
   GridView grid = new GridView();

        var query = (from a in db.table
                     where a.IDNumber.Equals(uc.ID_Number)
                    select a).ToList();
        var tt = query;
        grid.DataSource = tt.ToList();
        grid.DataBind();
        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=ResultsReport.xls");
        Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
        Response.Charset = "";
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
        string strPath = Request.PhysicalApplicationPat+"ResultsReport.xls";
        grid.RenderControl(htw);
        Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
        StreamWriter sWriter = new StreamWriter(strPath);
        sWriter.Write(sw.ToString());
        sWriter.Close(); 
        sWriter.Close();
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();
    }
```

and my code on another controller for sending email is:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(MailModel model)
    {

        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
            var fromEmail = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["adminEmail"].ToString();
            var ToEmail = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["receiverEmail"].ToString();
            mail.To.Add(ToEmail);
            mail.From = new MailAddress(fromEmail);
            mail.Subject = model.Subject;

            string Body = model.Body;
            mail.Body = Body;
            mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
            string strPath = "ResultsReport.xls";
            byte[] bytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
            //mail.Body = Body.Replace("\r\n", "<br />");
            mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(new MemoryStream(bytes), strPath));
            SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
            smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
            smtp.Port = 587;
            smtp.Timeout = 10000;
            smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential
            ("myemail@gmail.com", "mypassword.");// Enter seders User name and password
            smtp.EnableSsl = true;
            smtp.Send(mail);
            return RedirectToAction("Sent"); 
        }

        else
        {
            return View(model);
        }
    }
```

Comment: After your `ConnectToDatabse` method, is your file on disk as you expect? And has the expected contents? Get that going first, and then move on to the email part.

Comment: yes the file get downloaded with the correct data written on the file, but on the email attachment theres an empty file @johnathan

Comment: try breaking your mail.attachments.add line into 3 lines (new stream, new attachment, add) and put a breakpoint on the new stream. Is it null? I wonder if the pathing is off, as you specify a more full path when you write the file, and just a filename when you read it.